# How to count repetitions in a dataframe column in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr

I have srink a df and I have kept only two columns, which are airport names (origin and destiny):

```
Origin Destination
<chr>  <chr>      
1 LPPD   LEMD       
2 DAAE   LFML       
3 EDDH   UUEE       
4 LFLL   DAAS       
5 LFPO   LFSL       
6 UMKK   ULLI       
7 LFPO   LFBA       
8 LFPG   EDDN       
9 LFLL   LFRN       
10 LFPG   EDDW       
# … with more rows
```

Airport names are repeated on either columns. I would like to summarise the repeated airport names, and output the following:

```
Airports totalMovements takeoffs landings
```

Airports are the airport names (one appearance) that appear on both columns. Total_Movements are the sum of the number of times an airport name appears in the Origin column plus the times that appears in the Destiny colum. Takeoffs are the number of times that an airport name appears in the Origin column and finally, landings are the total number of times that an airport name appears on the Destiny column.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = 1:2)[, .(.N,  sum(variable == 'Origin'), 
          sum(variable == 'Destination')), value]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, everything()) %>%
  group_by(Airports = value) %>%
  summarise(
    totalMovements = n(),
    takeoffs = sum(name == 'Origin'),
    landings = sum(name == 'Destination')
  )
```

Output (based on the rows shown in your question):

```
# A tibble: 17 x 4
   Airports totalMovements takeoffs landings
   <fct>             <int>    <int>    <int>
 1 DAAE                  1        1        0
 2 EDDH                  1        1        0
 3 LFLL                  2        2        0
 4 LFPG                  2        2        0
 5 LFPO                  2        2        0
 6 LPPD                  1        1        0
 7 UMKK                  1        1        0
 8 DAAS                  1        0        1
 9 EDDN                  1        0        1
10 EDDW                  1        0        1
11 LEMD                  1        0        1
12 LFBA                  1        0        1
13 LFML                  1        0        1
14 LFRN                  1        0        1
15 LFSL                  1        0        1
16 ULLI                  1        0        1
17 UUEE                  1        0        1
```

If you'd like to stick to only using `dplyr`, you can also emulate the behaviour of `pivot_longer` by:

```
library(dplyr)

bind_rows(
  df %>% transmute(Airports = Origin, name = 'Origin'),
  df %>% transmute(Airports = Destination, name = 'Destination')
) %>%
  group_by(Airports) %>%
  summarise(
    totalMovements = n(),
    takeoffs = sum(name == 'Origin'),
    landings = sum(name == 'Destination')
  )
```